# how to register users to mongodb after open id connect authentication?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a backend API written in nodejs(authorization with oAuth2) using azure-passport-ad, my frontend angular 5(openId connect), and I`m using Azure AD for authentication, the thing is that our users will have two roles
"student", "admin", how can I make that difference of roles, does the token retrieved by the idP gives me a field with the kind of roles that users has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the roles in Azure AD as shown here: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad.

To define roles in an app, you will have to modify its manifest in AAD to something like this (other properties removed for brevity):

```
{
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Administrator",
      "id": "179c1dc0-4801-46f3-bc0d-35f059da1415",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Administrators can access advanced features.",
      "value": "admin"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can assign users to these roles via the Users and groups tab for the Enterprise application/service principal's blade.

The ID tokens sent to your app will then contain the role(s) like so:

```
{
  "family_name": "User",
  "given_name": "Test",
  "name": "Test User",
  "roles": [
    "admin"
  ]
}
```

You can check that claim after the token has been validated by Passport.

Comment: Is there any possibilty of creating custom roles? Because they are specifically for our app.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I described here. You can add roles for your app in its manifest and assign them to users.

Comment: the field "id" should contain my application  id from my REST API or the id of my Angular application

Comment: Well, the id will not be passed to your app, only the value.